# i am new to react and i am trying to run a project it throws error static/js/bundle.js failed

Tags: reactjs

[image]

need some insights regarding this, tried to setup new project too but still it shows the same error bundle.js failed
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
image is displayed above

Comment: just use       npx create-react-app my-app

Comment: yes sir, I did the same. I did create a new react application, but in the existing project the issue with bundle.js not found @AbuDujanaMahalail

Comment: You can find answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68029132/i-am-new-to-react-and-i-am-trying-to-run-a-project-it-throws-error-static-js-bun/68029469#68029469

Comment: yes sir it did help a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Resolve this issue, you have 3 options. You can choose any one.

1. You need to uninstall "KB5003637" windows security update. Here are the steps to uninstall update.

- Go to setting -> Update & security
- Click on view update history
- click on uninstall updates -> see attached screen shot for the reference
  [image]

2. You need to run your project with HTTP instead of HTTPS. You need to disable SSL from properties of the project. See attached image for reference.
   [image]
3. You need to change your project's .Net Core version to 5 if its 3 OR 3.1.

Comment: Thank You  so much sir 2nd one helped me fix this issue